# Reading / writing directly to SD Card with Android

Tags: android, c++, sd-card, android-sdcard

In my pure C++ native process (that I run from the terminal with adb) I'm trying to read a block directly from the SD Card in Android 2.3 SGS2. My code is running with root permissions so it shouldn't matter.

I know that the SD Card memory mapped to `/sys/block/mmcblk1` so I open it:

```
int fd = open("/sys/block/mmcblk1", O_RDONLY);
```

which succeeds. Now, when I'm trying to read from it:

```
bytes_read = read(fd, buffer, 4096);
```

I get an error: "Is a directory"

Well, I know that this is a directory but it's still supposed to work, maybe with some other flags in the open?

How can I do this?

Comment: Did the mounting successful ?

Comment: I don't do the mount operation, but it's already mounted because I can get into the /sys/block/mmcblk1 directory by adb shell and see what's in there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha!
My mistake was indeed that I tried to read from a directory `/sys/block/mmcblk1`.
But I should have try to read from `/dev/block/mmcblk1`!

Which works perfectly.